# Addthis: Display total shares

Tags: javascript, addthis, social-media

I would like to get the AddThis widget to display the total number of shares of an URL on Facebook, Twitter and Google+. Here comes my code:

```
<script src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>

<div addthis:url="http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" addthis:title="Wikipedia JavaScript page">
                        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
                    </div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ez8ya0ov/

How do I achieve that the total count of shares on facebook, twitter and google+ get displayed in a bubble on the right side? I do NOT want the individual numbers of each social media service get displayed (in this example I want to get rid of the bubble with "7" next to the google+ icon). Anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Fiddle does nothing.

Comment: are u sure? when i click on the link jsfiddle opens with the content i put in

Comment: The fiddle has nothing you speak of, such as
 `(in this example I want to get rid of the bubble with "7" next to the google+ icon)` so, what code have you tried?

Comment: it is displayed in the fiddle. you cannot see the social media icons and the "7" next to the Google+ icon?

Comment: Dude, the fiddle has *no result* drawn. there's nothing showing up.

Comment: that's very weird. does this link work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ez8ya0ov/1/#&togetherjs=dA4TM1PnGO

Comment: I can see you wobblying about BUT the result pane has nothing on it.

Comment: I still cannot understand why it doesn't work. Could you please create your own fiddle and paste inside the code provided in my post?